# Apach Ignite ClientCache::putIfAbsent don't actually update cache?

Tags: ignite, clientcache

```
cache.putIfAbsent(key, value);
cache.get(key).method();
```

Given code produces NPE at second line.
Here is how I create cache:

```
ClientCacheConfiguration cacheConfig = new ClientCacheConfiguration().setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED)                                                                                .setName("POSITION");
cache = igniteClient.getOrCreateCache(cacheConfig);
```

Comment: What is the type of `key`?

Comment: Key is my type "CurrencyPair". Here is hashCode:
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31 * left.hashCode() + right.hashCode();
    }
And here is left/right hashCode:
public int hashCode() {
        int hash = currencyType.ordinal(); // currencyType is ordinal
        hash ^= (hash << 13);
        hash ^= (hash >> 17);
        hash ^= (hash << 5);
        return hash;
    }

Comment: Please share a code snippet with reproducer, there is definitely a bug in your code

Comment: That's the problem. I can't reproduce it. And moreover the NPE disappeared after service restart.

Comment: Sounds good. Just in case - aren't there any removal operations by chance? Is it possible that a NULL value could be inserted as a value?

Comment: No. Only putIfAbsent with not null key/value.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to come up with a number of edge cases in which `put(1, "foo"); get(1)` returns `null`. This is confusing, I know - distributed systems often are.

The root problem is always the cache settings. Ignite historically has a couple of defaults which lean towards performance instead of consistency:

- [`CacheConfiguration.writeSynchronizationMode=PRIMARY_SYNC`](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration.html#setWriteSynchronizationMode-org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheWriteSynchronizationMode-) returns to control to the client while the backup nodes haven't been updated yet.
- [`CacheConfiuration.readFromBackup=true`](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration.html#setReadFromBackup-boolean-) allows to read from a backup - which might be lagging behind because of the `PRIMARY_SYNC`.

While both of these options have their perfectly valid use cases, you may want to set `writeSynchronizationMode=FULL_SYNC` and `readFromBackup=false` to enforce stronger consistency and avoid the mess.